# Переопределение toString(), hashCode(), equals() в абстрактном классе Java

Tags: java

Должны ли быть переопределены методы `toString()`, `hashCode()`, `equals()` в абстрактном классе, имеет ли это какой-нибудь смысл?

Comment: Не должны, но могут - зависит от ситуации.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Они могут быть переопределены в абстрактном классе, если вы планируете их использовать, например в потомках.

Comment: В потомках - это значит, что при переопределении toString() в классе потомке реализация будет в виде сначала вызова через super родительского метода toString, а затем уже вывода полей специфичных для класса потомка?

Comment: Не обязательно, не путайте с конструкторами. Переопределение метода подразумевает его полную замену в классе-потомке.

Comment: Да вы можете вызвать метод предка. Но в `toString` - это не так полезно, а вот `hashCode` и `equals` полезней.

Answer (score 4):

Данные методы не обязательно переопределять, если вы их не используете, в противном случае стоит их переопределить. К примеру вызов метода `toString()` у объекта вернет вам, что то вроде: `objectName@46e05420`. Смысла в таком методе мало. Поэтому этот метод переопределяют и выводят с помощью него нужную (или полную) информацию об объекте. Тоже самое с методами `hashCode()` и `equals()`, их стандартная реализация может не подходить для решения какой либо задачи. Соответственно смысл в этом есть!

Answer (score 4):

Это имеет смысл, когда в абстрактном классе находятся какие-то данные и по ним определяется хэш код и `equals`, которые будут вызваны в дочерних переопределенных методах `hashCode()`, `equals()`:
`super.hashCode()` и `super.equals()` соответсвенно,

для вычисления хэш кода и проверки на равенство в классах потомках, учитывая поля предка (абстрактного класса).